# Where is the Multichannel/Coaxial/SPDIF configuration option in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, spdif

I recently switched from 10.04 to 12.04. I did a fresh install. However I can't configure 5.1 surround with my coaxial/SPDIF home teather, simply because the new sound manager interface doesn't provide options like in 10.04. In 10.04 I could configure 'digital output + analogic input' and everything was ok, but in 12.04 I can't do this.

[image]

How can I change the configuration?

Comment: if you are happy with the answer - please click the tick button next to the answer to close this thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu disables and hides digital audio output SPDIF in all Realtek / Nvidia Cards by default in fact it  does same in all flavor of Ubuntu.

The procedure to fix it is the same in all versions of Ubuntu and works for all sound cards Ati Nvidia Realtek Creative Bosse etc. You need to edit a file to get it to work.  Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and type this:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

then add this line to the end of the file

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

At this time you need to reboot the machine, and the missing digital audio spdif will be working. Go to task bar icon to select proper device (which will be showing now) to avoid sound output to all speakers at the same time.

For spanish take this link: http://www.fermu.com/es/articulos/linux/48-ubuntu/773-configurar-audio-hdmi-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-una-tarjeta-gr%C3%A1fica-nvidia-geforce-8600m-gt-en-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have the same problem we have here, though in the opposite direction. Our fresh install of 12.04 32 bit won't let us switch from digital output to analog. Default will go to analog only if no other sound card hooked up (ie remove USB headphones).

[image: screenshot of pavucontrols configuration dialogue]

There is an option in `pavucontrol` to select between digital and analog outputs but it is not recognized by the default volume control and multiple outputs are not possible (application switching between streams is disabled).

Try [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) and see if you can access the additional configuration there?

Alternatively you can do the configuration with `pactl` via terminal, see the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pactl.1.html) for more details. Also you should check the `alsamixer` settings in terminal, sometimes you try searching the root cause in pulseaudio, while its alsa instead.

[image: alsamixer]